# Какой уровень изоляции использовать?

Tags: php, c++, node.js, postgresql, транзакции

Не могу понять как правильно работать с транзакциями и блокировками в postgres.

Идея параллельного доступа мне понятна в разрезе ЯПов (мьютексы, семафоры и т.п.).
Но с транзакциями всё иначе, раньше я думал, что просто используя FOR UPDATE (pessimistic_lock) я обойду ошибку конкурентного доступа (изменения и вставки), но ошибки не исчезли =).

Я не могу найти внятных примеров использования того или иного уровня изоляции транзакций для операций вставки\изменений.
Можете подсказать, как было бы правильнее использовать транзакции?

К примеру у нас есть три таблицы:

```
Пользователь ( id | money )

Книга ( id | buy_count | cost | user_id )

История покупок ( id | book_id | user_id (Покупатель) | commission )
```

Как было бы правильнее организовать следующие юзкейсы (уровень изоляции, тип блокировок):

- Добавление книги:
- - С автора (юзера) списывается 100 монет
- - Книга добавляется в таблицу книг
- Покупка книги:
- - С пользователя списываются монеты, указанная в стоимости
- - Зачисляется на счет автора 50%
- - Увеличить поле  "buy_count" на 1.
- - В таблицу истории покупок добавляется запись о покупке.
- Получение кол-ва продаж всех книг (тут скорее вопрос не про транзакции, а про производительность, т.е. до какого лимита по кол-ву записей можно на каждый запрос юзера проходиться по всей таблице и считать)

Эти юзкейсы скорее не просто про SQL запросы, но также и про то, как лучше обработать ошибки параллельного доступа (если от них невозможно избавиться).